# Jquery getJSON populate select menu - security

Tags: php, security, getjson

I'm using this function with getJSON for populating select menu.

```
$.getJSON('get_province.php', {id:$('#customer_city').val()}, function(data) {
      var select = document.getElementById("customer_province");
      $('option', select).remove();

      $.each(data, function(index, array) {
        select.add(new Option(array['province_name']));
      });
      $("#customer_province").select2("val", "");
    });
```

and this is get_province.php

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password_conn);
$rows = array();
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT province_name FROM db WHERE city_code= ? ORDER BY province_name");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); }
echo json_encode($rows);
```

It's working. 
But users can run get_province.php alone like that. .ttp://blabla.net/get_province.php?id=1 and can see the results. How can I prevent to access php file alone?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. If the user needs to access it via `AJAX`, it can be access via a browser

Comment: You can't. It's a webpage. There's no reliable method to detect if a hit on that url came from your ajax code, or from someone poking it directly.

Comment: Why does it matter?  It's not like province names are something you need to even worry about securing.  Outside of that, you would be looking at passing a session token back and forth to validate the end user and that the are coming from correct spot in your application.

Comment: There are *multiple methods* possible

Comment: This was just simple sample. I want to learn methods if its possible. I will use this method for different cascading dropdowns, forexample; user_list from companies.. User can run php with company id, and can see users list... @MikeBrant

Comment: Well security can't really be covered in a simple SO question.  I recommend you read up on cross-site request forgery and session hijacking attacks and appropriate means for mitigation, as these seem like the two most significant attack vectors for this use case.

Comment: in get_province.php you must check if the user has the permissions to get those data, before returning them (how to do that depends on your application structure, login method etc..)

Answer (score -2):

Method 1:
Easily spoofable but very easy to setup. It'll work best if you only have page calling it but if you have multiple you can just change it to check through an array of valid referers. Also in some user agents that will not be sent so it isn't great for that reason as well. Just add something like this to the top of your provinces.php:

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== '%good referer address%') {
    echo "</p>some sort of warning if you want</p>";
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Unauthorized");
    exit;
  }
```

Method 2:
Use session handling and verified users. This is a fairly significant project but it will be very solid and as hard to spoof as your user system security.

Method 3:
create a unique *one use* code on your requesting page and send it with the ajax request. Good and very hard to spoof - you can also use this in combination with method 2 to make sure that verified users can't access via browser url entry as well.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` isn't a required header and could disable the ajax for actual users. All methods are easy to spoof and the only reason you would want to block your AJAX request is from scripters. Normal users/searchbots don't access it anyway.

Comment: As I said #1 is easily spoofable, Method 2 is fairly guaranteed, method 3 is second best

Comment: The problem with #1 is not that it's spoofable, it's that not every browser/user sends the referer. If a valid user doesn't send it, your site won't work. #2 doesnt guarentuee anything. If I can see the AJAX request i'm verified, so I can access the content directly. #3 has the same problem as #2